# Javascript to help disability people

Tags: javascript, html

I have a cousin with difficulties on his arms and he uses a small piece of 
toothpick to type in his keyboard.

I know there are TONS of apps around to help him use his keyboard more easily but I was wondering I could make a very customized script with JS using a Chrome Extension so I could create some nice functions to ease his browsing.

So far, my biggest problem was NOT firing `keydown` event, but actually simulating the REAL PRESS OF THE KEY with it's effect in place (if I hit the left arrow inside an input, the cursor would move left)... I couldn't do it easily but I was relying on `oninput` event to trigger real key press. With a small code like below I code easily simulate a real key press:

```
var my_event = document.createEvent("TextEvent");    
my_event.initTextEvent("textInput",true,false,window,"T");

document.getElementById("test").focus();

document.getElementById("test").dispatchEvent(my_event);
```

This code would make the letter T appear in the carret position of any input/textarea or contenteditable element (like div). But this code does not work anymore cause from version 52 to 53 of Chrome they did this:

> "Events generated by script will no longer trigger default actions, improving spec compliance and browser interop"

So how can I overcome this? I don't want to simulate key press, events... NO! There is a ton of material around in the internet about this. I want a real `keypress` with all of its glory and effects and events.

Comment: does your cousin use a mouse? if so, perhaps utilizing mouse events to trigger the other events would be a solution...

Comment: no, it's way harder to use a toothpick to move a mouse than a keyboard. Have you ever seen a disabled person using a toothpick to browse internet?